# In django function base view how to inherit some opertion that are used in all views functions?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am using django function base views these operation needed in all views.

```
    resourceList=resource.objects.all()
    params={
     'resourcelist':resourceList
    }
    return render(request, html file, params)
```

One solution is that I will type in all my views function. Anyone can help me with a suitable answer for this?

Comment: Why don't you use a custom context processor to add `resourcelist` to every context automatically https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function of the repeated code and call it where you need it.
In your case, you can do:

```
def common_code_function(request,html_file_name):
    resourceList=resource.objects.all()
    params={
        'resourcelist':resourceList
    }
    return render(request, html_file_name, params)
```

Comment: but how can I get this common function for different html pages??